# How to fix SQLLiteDesignTimeServices in OS X for visual studio code and asp.net 5 ? EF7 related

Tags: c#, asp.net, macos, entity-framework, sqlite

On my MBP, I used Yeoman aspnet-generator template to create an ASP.net 5 template web application.

I am able to run the web application and view the pages, but unable to register or create login using the standard template.

Tried to run the following command:

```
dnx ef database update
```

The following is the error I get

```
ystem.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqliteDesignTimeServices, EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design' from assembly ''.
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.ConfigureProviderServices (System.String provider, IServiceCollection services, Boolean throwOnError) <0x6113ea8 + 0x00023> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.Internal.DesignTimeServicesBuilder.Build (Microsoft.Data.Entity.DbContext context) <0x5eed310 + 0x00133> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Design.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase (System.String targetMigration, System.String contextType) <0x5cc51b8 + 0x00039> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor+<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<UpdateDatabase>b__0 () <0x3720dc8 + 0x00034> in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Microsoft.Data.Entity.Commands.Program+Executor.Execute (System.Action action) <0x3720d48 + 0x0001c> in <filename unknown>:0 
Could not load type 'Microsoft.Data.Entity.Scaffolding.SqliteDesignTimeServices, EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design' from assembly ''.
```

Answer (score 0):

Add to your project.json the following dependency:

```
"EntityFramework.Sqlite.Design": "7.0.0-rc1-final"
```

And then please run:

```
dnu restore
```

then

```
dnx ef database update
```

should work.